# My celery redis task isn't working in my django app on heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, redis

I have a task that was working fine on my local server but when I pushed it to Heroku, nothing happens. there are no error messages. I am a newbie when it comes to this and locally I would start the worker by doing

```
celery worker -A blog -l info.
```

So I'm guessing that's the issue may have to do with that. because I don't know to do this. I doubt I'm supposed to do this in my app. heres my code

celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gettingstarted.settings'
)

app = Celery('blog')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

my tasks.py

```
import requests
import random
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .celery import app
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@app.task
def the_star():
    def swappo():
        user_one = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" '
        user_two = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)" '
        user_thr = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" '
        user_for = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0" '

        agent_list = [user_one, user_two, user_thr, user_for]
        a = random.choice(agent_list)
        return a

    headers = {
        "user-agent": swappo(),
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }

    # scraping from worldstar
    url_to = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url_to, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')
    name = 'World Star'

    if os.getenv('_system_name') == 'OSX':
        author = User.objects.get(id=2)
    else:
        author = User.objects.get(id=3)

    def make_soup(url):
        the_comments_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(the_comments_page.text, 'html5lib')
        comment = soupdata.find('div')
        para = comment.find_all('p')
        kids = [child.text for child in para]
        blu = str(kids).strip('[]')
        return blu

    cleaned_titles = [title for title in titles if title.a.get('href') != 'vsubmit.php']
    world_entries = [{'href': url_to + box.a.get('href'),
                      'src': box.img.get('src'),
                      'text': box.strong.a.text,
                      'comments': make_soup(url_to + box.a.get('href')),
                      'name': name,
                      'url': url_to + box.a.get('href'),
                      'embed': None,
                      'author': None,
                      'video': False
                      } for box in cleaned_titles][:10] # The count

    for entry in world_entries:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        title = post.title
        if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
            post.title = entry['text']
            post.name = entry['name']
            post.url = entry['url']
            post.body = entry['comments']
            post.image_url = entry['src']
            post.video_path = entry['embed']
            post.author = entry['author']
            post.video = entry['video']
            post.status = 'draft'
            post.save()
            post.tags.add("video", "Musica")
    return world_entries
```

my views.py

```
def shopan(request):
    the_star.delay()
    return redirect('/')
```

I have multiple instances of REDIS_URL

soI ran

```
heroku redis:promote REDIS_URL
```

and that's what I use in my environment variable which you can see above. How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an entry in your Procfile to tell Heroku to start the Celery worker:

```
worker:celery worker -A blog -l info
```

Comment: I just did what you said and pushed it to my server but nothing happened. I went back to the docs and searched for procfile and it said heroku ps:scale worker=1, I tried to do that and it said Couldn't find that formation

Comment: I had to space it out so there was space between the colon and celery like this worker: celery worker -A blog -l info and then I had to run heroku ps:scale worker=1 and ot worked